# Mysql Normalization

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have three tables

```
USER TABLE
userid  username
1       alpha

Email TABLE
id  userid email
1   1      alpha1@test.com
2   1      alpha2@test.com
3   1      alpha3@test.com

Phonenumber TABLE
id  userid  phonenumber
1   1       123456
2   1       123457
3   1       123458
```

How can i get the below result using a single query

```
userid username email           phonenumber
1      alpha    alpha1@test.com 123456
1      alpha    alpha2@test.com 123457
1      alpha    alpha3@test.com 123458
```

Comment: I hope above normalization is only for example, otherwise new table for each column is useless :)

Comment: I know i can do it by join but i am getting 9 rows. So i just need 3 rows a result mentioned in my question

Comment: How do you know which email belongs to which phone number?

Comment: What if there were 4 email addresses and 2 phone numbers? What will be the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a version of your data that's not normalized at all, and add some additional, reasonable data so we can see how normalization works here. (Assumes everyone has at least one email address and one phone number, simply to avoid talking about nulls.)

```
userid  username  email             phonenumber
1       Alpha     alpha1@test.com   123456
1       Alpha     alpha2@test.com   123457
1       Alpha     alpha3@test.com   123458
2       Beta      beta1@test.com    234567
2       Beta      beta2@test.com    234567      (2 email addresses, 1 phone)
3       Gamma     gamma1@test.com   234678
3       Gamma     gamma1@test.com   234679      (1 email address, 2 phones)
4       Alpha     alpha32@test.com  345678      (2 people, #1 and #4, with same name)
```

If you look closely at that data, you'll find that **the only key is {email, phonenumber}**.

That's why you're having trouble getting only three rows--that key is nowhere in your tables.  This is what @ontrack was getting at by saying, "Your tables do not have a unique relation between emails and phone-numbers."

Following the algorithm for determining candidate keys in any database textbook will give you the same thing.  AFAIK, *every* textbook on database theory has at least one algorithm for determining candidate keys.

Obviously, if you had a table that had {email, phonenumber} as the key, you'd get only 3 rows for userid 1.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i dont have choice because i can not make any changes in the production database. All i have to play with mysql queries. if this is not possible to fetch data using mysql then definitely i will have to handle this at script level.

Comment: @neeraj: You can't handle that at the script level, because the facts you need aren't in the database. If Phonenumber.id and Email.id are autoincrement integers (a reasonable assumption on our part), there's no deterministic way to tell that 'alpha1@test.com' should be paired with '123456' instead of '123458'.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my another query at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16173/creat-temporary-id-in-sql-statement If there is a solution for that query then i think i can find solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your problem, but have you considered using `group_concat()`?

```
SELECT userid, username, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT phonenumber) 
FROM Email 
LEFT JOIN Phonenumber USING (userid) 
LEFT JOIN User USING (userid)
GROUP BY userid
```

It should give you this result:

```
userid username  email                                           phonenumber
1      alpha     alpha1@test.com,alpha2@test.com,alpha3@test.com 123456,123457,123458
```

Maybe this will solve your original problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didnt use group_concat() because it return a result in a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply. By **[joining](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)** your tables.

Try below:

```
SELECT u.userid,u.username,e.email,p.phonenumber 
FROM User as u LEFT JOIN Email as e on u.userid=e.userid
LEFT JOIN Phonenumber as p on u.userid=p.userid
```

Comment: I know i can do it by  join but i am getting 9 rows. So i just need 3 rows a result mentioned in my question

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not a right query as i am still getting 9 rows. You first try to understand the question that how would i need the result then write the query and run

Comment: Your tables do not have a unique relation between emails and phone-numbers. If those email-adresses are different in each row, how should the query know that a certain phone-number relates to that? So it is possible to get 3 rows out of this query by using DISTINCT. But you should understand AND explain first what it is you're trying to retrieve and why it should result in 3 rows.

Comment: There is a relationship between user, email and phonenumber on the basis of userid of user table. Now I know distinct will give me unique rows but i want to get rows from each table (email and phonenumber) as a column. This is the very general scenario where different table is used to save multiple values of the base table. Do you want to say that this normalization can not work ??

Comment: @neeraj :Normalization is ok. You getting 9 rows that is also ok. Because that is the way how join works. You need to make logic in your programming script with array to get what you asking

Comment: @KingFisher I know we can get/make such result from the script but I  JUST WOULD LIKE TO KNOW THAT IS THIS NOT POSSIBLE TO GET SUCH RESULT USING MYSQL?

Comment: Joining everything together will give you 9 rows because there is no relation between the first row of the email-adresses and the first row of the phone-numbers. Why does the first email-adress relate to the first phone-number. You will have to specify this in your model else it is indeed not properly normalized.

Comment: @Neeraj: I am not sure if we can do with stored procedure or not. But with single query it's not possible.

Comment: @KingFisher Okay i just wanted to know if this is possible or not. Now i would ask you that if you are given such database tables from the client then how will you resolve it?

Comment: Wil not take headace of doing with query. Will make my custom array looping around query result with programming  script. Because I konw if it will be possible by any mean then performance of query will be low

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT userid, username, email, phonenumber FROM Email LEFT JOIN
>   Phonenumber USING (userid) LEFT JOIN User USING (userid)

Comment: This is giving 9 rows. I need just 3 rows